# How to Permanently Delete Photos from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, storage

I have so many photos on the iPhone. And my iPhone's internal space is not enough now.

Comment: Let's see if anyone has a ready answer. If not, we can help you edit your question to provide more details on what you've tried, what exactly you don't get. See the guides on [about] and [ask] if you don't get an answer and decide to edit your question. They are often helpful in refining / reframing your query.

Comment: If you want to delete photos on your phone to recover space - try this app http://getflic.com/ helps a lot

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you're not looking to securely delete these photos, just recover space that they're consuming, as suggested by your original question, let's just start simply...

Aside from the suggestions by superriku11, including using iPhoto to transfer them off with the delete option and Image Capture, you do realize that you can, in Photos in your Camera Roll select Edit and then proceed to select a series of photos and then Delete them. This is time consuming for lots of photos, but does allow you directly on the iPhone to get rid of images you may no longer want to keep. This is the obvious solution to getting rid of multiple images at once but some people forget about it. Realize that if you delete a photo in the Camera Roll that's in an Album it goes away there too. You can delete albums using the Edit button, but this keeps images in the Camera Roll.

If you want to get rid of all the photos in your Camera Roll all at once, go into Settings > General > Usage under Storage click Photos & Camera and the right swipe Camera Roll to bring up a Delete button. Give it some time and it will delete all your photos in the Camera Roll. Likewise you could delete all the photos in your Photo Library and/or Photo Stream the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Must they be permanently (securely) deleted? If not, simply deleting them regularly should suffice. There's a delete option while viewing the picture. That's pretty slow though, so here's some faster options:

- There's an option in iPhoto (if you use that) to delete photos after transferring.
- If you're able to access the iPhone photos through another method that allows you to delete photos (such as the fact that an iPhone presents a USB interface on other systems than OS X) you can delete them much more quickly and easily too.
- I haven't used it in a while, but I think Image Capture on OS X may provide a way to delete pictures from the camera (your iPhone) as well. If so, it may provide an option to bulk delete.

If the photos must indeed be securely deleted, the question is how secure. Tests on Solid State Drives (SSDs) have shown that even with standard deletion, the data is almost entirely irrecoverable afterwards. The NAND storage that iPhones use is likely similar.

If you absolutely need a secure delete though, it may be possible through running a secure delete tool such as `srm` (OS X) or `shred` (nearly the same thing, for Linux systems) on the photos if you can connect to the iPhone via USB interface. To be more sure, you should run a secure erase command from the phone itself, which would probably require it to be jailbroken and you to SSH into the phone or use a terminal program.

Answer (score 0):

*please only do this, if you know what you are doing!*

Under Linux:

Plug your iPhone via USB.

Open your file explorer (I used Nautilus) and navigate to your iPhone -> DCIM.

Right-click the folder 100APPLE -> "open terminal".

In the Shell, delete photos using the `rm` command.

Answer (score 0):

If deleting them from Image capture or the device itself doesn’t work, make a backup and then [consider restoring](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/194458/5472).