# Delete Camera Roll Images

Tags: iphone, ios

What is the best way to delete all images from camera roll.  I am selling my phone and don't want to try deleting them one at a time, nor do I want to leave them.

Answer (score 2):

Connect the iPhone to a Mac or PC running iTunes and do a complete [Restore to factory settings](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252). This will wipe out all media & data and install the latest version of iOS for that device.

If you don't have a Mac or PC for this task, on the iPhone itself, you can go to Settings > General > Reset > Erase all content and settings.

**NOTE**: Be sure to disable Find My iPhone if you have it enabled, and logout of any iCloud services.

Comment: With newer OS, [selecting one image and then shift selecting another](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/415449/5472) can get a nice range selection.