# How to remove a large number of photos on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, photos.app, macos

I would like to remove a large set of photos ( some hundreds ) on my iPhone with
`Photos` application
or any other application providing this basic function.

I am looking for something as efficient and simple stupid as <kbd>⇧</kbd>+[click] and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+[click] in `Photos` on macOS.

I have already tried many usual suspects to extend first photo selection: [home]+[click], [long click], [heavy click], [double click], [upper left button]+[click]…
while keeping track of all combinations tried to avoid repeating. I didn't find any way to do a <kbd>⇧</kbd>+[click].

Thus far I didn't find it and nonetheless I am convinced this is
a vital function, then it has to exist. The only challenge is to find where Apple might have hidden it.

I am not using any cloud service, and I don't want to.

Which is the best way to achieve this simple task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Drag to select

There's a touch gesture that allows you to select a large amount of photos really quickly.

To use it, go to Photos app, and, when in an album or library, tap "Select".

[image: Screenshot taken on iPhone of the photo library (Recents) showing with an arrow the Select button]

Then, make a really short swipe (left or right - don't make a large move or it won't work) *on* the bottom/top photo of the list you want to select and move your finger towards the top or bottom of your screen to select photos<sup>1</sup>.

Make sure you **do not release your finger** until you have finished selecting what you want or you will have to perform the above steps again (and might have some photos missed - not selected).

[image: Screenshot taken on iPhone explaining how to drag to select in Photos]

After having selected the wanted photos, you can perform the action of your choice (share, delete, etc.) which will apply to all photos selected.

For more information and guidance on this, check out [Delete photos on your iPhone or iPad - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT205856).

<sup><sup>1</sup>This also works when you have already selected photo(s) one by one.</sup>

---

For those who are interested, the photos present in the screenshots are pictures of *[Composition with Red, Blue, and Yellow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_with_Red_Blue_and_Yellow)* by Mondrian.

Comment: + for the cultural add ;).

Comment: Did you notice when the swipe move has to start to fire the "extend selection"?

Comment: @dan I think it needs to start after having selected one photo. From there, just drag you finger across the screen to selecr some more.

Comment: I would name this finger gesture a swipe.
2 notes of interest ( which could explain so many people ignore this function ) :
- it doesn't work if you start to swipe down or up,
- it doesn't work if you just wait one second on the 1st selected photo.

Comment: @dan Actually, no need to select the first photo, just a little swipe right or left on a photo will trigger the selecting. ;)